# JQuery Remove Parent List Item

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
 <ul class="media-list">
    <li class="media post">
       <div class="media-left">
           <a href="#"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="media-body">
          <div class="post-content">
               <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="post-actions clearfix">
             <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
               <li>
                  <a class="js-delete-post" data-post-id="24" href="#">
                    Delete
                  </a>
               </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="media post">
      ...
   </li>
</ul>
```

When I click js-delete-post anchor I want to remove the parent li with class "media post".

The following Jquery simply traverses one level up and removes the li of the js-delete-class. How do I traverse an additional level up to remove the post.

```
$(".js-delete-post").click(function (e) {
    var a = $(this); // "this" is the <a>

     a.parents("li").fadeOut(function () {
                $(this).remove();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `closest` instead of `parents` and then select it by the classes too.

```
a.closest("li.media.post").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you may continue to use parents but you need to add the classes of the element you are looking for: $(this).parents("li.media.post")

Without the classes parents will return two elements.

This is possible because there is only one ancestor element with those characteristics.

In any case I suggest the closest method:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".js-delete-post").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parents("li.media.post").fadeOut(function () {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<ul class="media-list">
  <li class="media post">
    <div class="media-left">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="post-content">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="post-actions clearfix">
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
          <li>
            <a class="js-delete-post" data-post-id="24" href="#">
              Delete
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="media post">
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```